# Best practice to hide rows in JavaFX TableView

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I looking for best way to hide rows in table based on some criteria.

Right now I have table with dynamically updated rows(with relatively high frequency). Based on user input, rows, which do not meet certain criteria, should be hided.

So I was thinking about having two models with data - first, which hold all available items, and second, linked to TableView. When data in first model meet criteria, it will be added to second list, if not - removed.

Maybe there are some more ideas how to solve this problem more elegant?